# RMI dynamic class loading in java, how to separate and launch code on localhost?

Tags: java, rmi, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a bit confusion about how dynamic class loading mechanism works. I implemented below classes and when they are all in the same src directory and i launch them from my ide, server and client works. But when i separate them i can't make it work. There are many guides that explaining how RMI works etc but they don't explain how should i separate files and launch them one everything is ok.

So what i have done:
Compiled all classes and obtained corrisponding .class files. Then i created a folder and subfolders to separate client, server and common classes:

```
home/
|-myuser/
  |--rmitest/
     |--server/ 
     |   Server.class
     |-- client/
     |   Client.class, client.policy
     |-- common/
         NotifyEventImpl.class, NotifyEventInterface.class, ServerImpl.class, ServerInterface.class
```

This is a homework question server and client will both work on localhost. Anyway, then whe i launch server with

```
$ java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=/home/myuser/rmitest/common/ Server .
```

it can't find classes

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServerImpl
    at Server.main(Server.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

So how should i do it to get it work? My seperation of classes is correct? How should i launch server and client? Thanks.

Below you find my classes:

```
public interface ServerInterface extends Remote{
    void registerForCallback(NotifyEventInterface clientInterface) 
                                                throws RemoteException;
}
```

---

```
public class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface {
        private List<NotifyEventInterface> clients;

        public ServerImpl() throws RemoteException{
            super();
            clients = new ArrayList<NotifyEventInterface>();
        }

        public synchronized void registerForCallback(NotifyEventInterface ClientInterface) throws RemoteException{
            if(!clients.contains(ClientInterface)){
                clients.add(ClientInterface);
                System.out.println("New client registered");
            }
        }


        public void update(int value) throws RemoteException {
            doCallbacks(value);
        }

        private synchronized void doCallbacks(int value) throws RemoteException {
            System.out.println("Starting callbacks");
            Iterator i = clients.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                NotifyEventInterface client = (NotifyEventInterface) i.next();
                client.notifyEvent(value);
            }
            System.out.println("Callbacks complete");
        }

}
```

---

```
public class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                ServerImpl serverObj = new ServerImpl();
                int portNum = 39000;
                startRegistry(portNum);
                String registryUrl = "//:" + portNum + "/common";
                Naming.rebind(registryUrl, serverObj);
                System.out.println("Server is ready");


                while(true){
                    int val = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
                    System.out.println("New update " + val);
                    serverObj.update(val);
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                }

        }

        private static void startRegistry(int rmiPortNum) throws RemoteException{
            try {
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmiPortNum);
                registry.list( );
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                System.out.println("RMI registry is not located at port " + rmiPortNum);
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiPortNum);
                System.out.println("RMI registry created at port " + rmiPortNum);
            }
        }

}
```

---

```
public interface NotifyEventInterface extends Remote {
    void notifyEvent(int value) throws RemoteException;
}
```

---

```
public class NotifyEventImpl implements NotifyEventInterface{
        public NotifyEventImpl() throws RemoteException{
            super();
        }


        @Override
        public void notifyEvent(int value) throws RemoteException {
            String returnMessage = "Update event received " + value;
            System.out.println(returnMessage);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Compiled all classes and obtained corrisponding .class files. Then i created a folder and subfolders to separate client, server and common classes

Wrong. You should separate them first, at source code level, with corresponding package statements in the source code. Then compile. The compiler will then put the .class files into a directory structure corresponding to the package hierarchy.

NB `ServerImpl` is not a common class. It is only used by the server.

Comment: Thanks. So if i add like `import common.NotifyEventInterface` (all needed classes) to Client and compile them all together, is it ok?
Now that it works but when i make jar files for client,server and common, i can't make it work. 
`java -cp common/Common.jar:server/Server.jar -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/path/rmitest/common/Common.jar" -jar server/Server.jar `
How should i launch it?

Comment: No sorry, infact when i compile them in their packages under same src, it works from the ide but if i launch it from command line, it doesn't work.(its without jar, with jar i cant make it work still)